# Flashing Text in PyGame

Tags: python, text, pygame

How do I make flashing text in PyGame? Here's the piece of text I'm trying to flash once every second or so:

```
text = pygame.font.Font("c:/windows/fonts/visitor1.ttf", 50)

textsurf, textrect = text_objects("Press Any Key To Start", text)

textrect.center = ((res_w / 2), (res_h / 2))

screen.blit(textsurf, textrect)
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to have it flashing you'll have to draw it for a second then delete it for a second repeat this over and over again.  For timing the blinking a custom timer event can be used.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from itertools import cycle
import pygame

VISITOR_TTF_FILENAME = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/aenigma/visitor1.ttf'
BLINK_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 0


def main():
    pygame.init()
    try:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        font = pygame.font.Font(VISITOR_TTF_FILENAME, 50)
        on_text_surface = font.render(
            'Press Any Key To Start', True, pygame.Color('green3')
        )
        blink_rect = on_text_surface.get_rect()
        blink_rect.center = screen_rect.center
        off_text_surface = pygame.Surface(blink_rect.size)
        blink_surfaces = cycle([on_text_surface, off_text_surface])
        blink_surface = next(blink_surfaces)
        pygame.time.set_timer(BLINK_EVENT, 1000)

        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return
                if event.type == BLINK_EVENT:
                    blink_surface = next(blink_surfaces)

            screen.blit(blink_surface, blink_rect)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)
    finally:
        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Instead of going completetly black in the off phase one could also blit the text in a darker color.

Encapsulating the blinking text in a type derived from Pygame's `Sprite` might help to keep the code clear if there is going on much more in the initialisation and the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing as @BlackJack https://stackoverflow.com/users/3815611/blackjack
but I made the off_text_surface transparent:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from itertools import cycle
import pygame

VISITOR_TTF_FILENAME = 'pixelFont.ttf'
BLINK_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 0
empty = (255,255,255,0)


def main():
    pygame.init()
    try:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        font = pygame.font.Font(VISITOR_TTF_FILENAME, 50)
        on_text_surface = font.render(
            'Press Any Key To Start', True, pygame.Color('green3')
        )
        blink_rect = on_text_surface.get_rect()
        blink_rect.center = screen_rect.center
        off_text_surface = pygame.Surface(blink_rect.size)
        off_text_surface.fill(empty)
        
        blink_surfaces = cycle([on_text_surface, off_text_surface])
        blink_surface = next(blink_surfaces)
        pygame.time.set_timer(BLINK_EVENT, 1000)

        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return
                if event.type == BLINK_EVENT:
                    blink_surface = next(blink_surfaces)

            screen.blit(blink_surface, blink_rect)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)
    finally:
        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```